# SPFx React Application Crash/Freezes Browser while Add on SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint, browser, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created a web part using SPFx React. Below is my package

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.14.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.14.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.11.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "7.174.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.1"
```

This web part is working correctly under the local workbench https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

When I generate a package of that app and add that to the SharePoint page (https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso/SitePages/contoso.aspx). It Freezes the Browser and returns the below errors.

1. not enough memory to open this page
2. Something went wrong while displaying the webpage

Can anyone help me with the same?